# Getting Placename, lat long from place picker and show in maps

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to make a simple program..
when the first button is clicked. placepicker is opened. .. a place is picked and the mainactivity is opened again.. when the second button is clicked.. I want to pass the Place name , Lat and long to pass to the showInMaps activity.. but when this activity is opened .. Application Stopped. Please help

MainActvity.java

```
package com.example.akshay.myapplication;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button chooseLoc , showInMap;
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder;
    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    public LatLng gotLatLng;
    String placeName;
    String plName;
   Double gotLat, gotLong;


static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chooseLoc = (Button) findViewById((R.id.bOpenMap));
        showInMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bShowInMap);
        chooseLoc.setOnClickListener(this);
        showInMap.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.bOpenMap:
            chooseLoc();
                break;
            case R.id.bShowInMap:

                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this , showInMaps.class);
                in.putExtra("pName", plName);
                gotLat= gotLatLng.latitude;
                gotLong = gotLatLng.longitude;
                in.putExtra("Lat", gotLat);
                in.putExtra("Log", gotLong);

                startActivity(in);
                break;

        }
    }

    public void chooseLoc()

    {
        try {
            intentBuilder =new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

            Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(MainActivity.this);


            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error In Repairable");
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Play Services is not available.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error In NotAvail");
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
                gotLatLng = place.getLatLng();
                plName = (String) place.getName();
                placeName = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
                Toast.makeText(this, placeName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(this, plName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }



}
```

showInMaps.java

```
package com.example.akshay.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 7/12/2015.
 */
public class showInMaps extends Activity {
    Double lat, longi;
    GoogleMap mMaps;
    String place;
    String latLong;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showinmaps);

        GoogleMap mMaps = null;

        Intent gotIntent = new Intent();

        place = gotIntent.getStringExtra("plName");
        lat = gotIntent.getExtras().getDouble("Lat");
        longi = gotIntent.getExtras().getDouble("Log");





        if (mMaps == null) {
            LatLng mm = new LatLng(lat, longi);
            mMaps = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            mMaps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mm).title("Hello"));

        }
    }
}
```

activitymain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Place"
        android:id="@+id/bOpenMap"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show In Map"
        android:id="@+id/bShowInMap"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bOpenMap"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

showinmaps.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.akshay.myapplication" >



    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCuZFbNaf6RGqU0C4uDAbNJQgMTDlsKqqE"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".showInMaps"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.akshay.myapplication.SHOWINMAPS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
07-12 15:28:43.016     955-1758/? E/PersonaManagerService﹕ inState():  stateMachine is null !!
07-12 15:28:43.026     955-1258/? E/ActivityManager﹕ checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
07-12 15:28:43.026     955-1258/? E/ActivityManager﹕ checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
07-12 15:28:43.026     955-1258/? E/ActivityManager﹕ checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
07-12 15:28:43.026     955-1258/? E/ActivityManager﹕ checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
07-12 15:28:43.036    2399-2399/com.example.akshay.myapplication E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
07-12 15:28:43.036    2399-2399/com.example.akshay.myapplication E/Zygote﹕ v2
07-12 15:28:43.046    2399-2399/com.example.akshay.myapplication E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
07-12 15:28:45.706     955-1756/? E/PersonaManagerService﹕ inState():  stateMachine is null !!
07-12 15:28:46.016     955-1004/? E/LocSvc_utils_cfg﹕ W/loc_read_sec_gps_conf: no secgps conf file, using defaults
07-12 15:28:46.046     955-1004/? E/LocSvc_utils_cfg﹕ W/loc_read_sec_gps_conf: no secgps conf file, using defaults
07-12 15:28:46.076     955-1006/? E/Sensors﹕ Sensor : Meta event
07-12 15:28:46.096     955-1537/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiV02::startFix(const LocPosMode&):434]: position_mode=0.
07-12 15:28:46.116     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalRespCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientRespIndUnionType, void*) line 125 QMI_LOC_SET_OPERATION_MODE_REQ_V02
07-12 15:28:46.126     955-1537/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiV02::startFix(const LocPosMode&):434]: position_mode=0.
07-12 15:28:46.156     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalRespCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientRespIndUnionType, void*) line 125 QMI_LOC_SET_OPERATION_MODE_REQ_V02
07-12 15:28:46.176      955-955/? E/LocSvc_flp﹕ I/===> int flp_inject_location(FlpLocation*) line 222
07-12 15:28:46.186     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source 10034 txSuccessRate=9.97 rxSuccessRate=8.87 targetRoamBSSID=90:f6:52:77:9b:f0 RSSI=-69
07-12 15:28:46.186     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ [1,436,695,126,196 ms] noteScanStartWorkSource{10034} uid 10034
07-12 15:28:46.206     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_ENGINE_STATE_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:46.226     955-1006/? E/Sensors﹕ Sensor : Meta event
07-12 15:28:47.066     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:47.726     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:47.786     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:48.366     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ [1,436,695,128,369 ms] noteScanEnd WorkSource{10034}
07-12 15:28:48.366     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ wifi setScanResults statecom.android.server.wifi.WifiStateMachine$ConnectedState@3f98adf2 sup_state=COMPLETED debouncing=false
07-12 15:28:48.406      955-955/? E/LocSvc_flp﹕ I/===> int flp_inject_location(FlpLocation*) line 222
07-12 15:28:48.716     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:48.776     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:48.956      337-853/? E/audio_hw_primary﹕ [MAXIM] setDSM_tx_Control()....dsm_enable : 0, dsm_opened : 1, adev->mode : 0
07-12 15:28:48.976      337-853/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ releaseWakeLock_l() AudioOut_4
07-12 15:28:49.726     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:49.786     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:50.726     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:50.786     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:51.226     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source 10034 txSuccessRate=8.99 rxSuccessRate=2.22 targetRoamBSSID=90:f6:52:77:9b:f0 RSSI=-71
07-12 15:28:51.226     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ [1,436,695,131,232 ms] noteScanStartWorkSource{10034} uid 10034
07-12 15:28:51.236     955-1006/? E/Sensors﹕ Sensor : Meta event
07-12 15:28:51.726     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:51.796     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:52.706     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:52.766     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:53.406     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ [1,436,695,133,409 ms] noteScanEnd WorkSource{10034}
07-12 15:28:53.426     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ wifi setScanResults statecom.android.server.wifi.WifiStateMachine$ConnectedState@3f98adf2 sup_state=COMPLETED debouncing=false
07-12 15:28:53.536      955-955/? E/LocSvc_flp﹕ I/===> int flp_inject_location(FlpLocation*) line 222
07-12 15:28:53.716     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:53.776     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:53.936    1967-2265/? E/Places﹕ e.a:898: GLS returned HTTP response code 500
07-12 15:28:54.376    1967-2265/? E/Places﹕ e.a:898: GLS returned HTTP response code 500
07-12 15:28:54.726     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:54.786     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:55.726     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_GNSS_SV_INFO_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:55.786     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:55.806      337-853/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ AudioFlinger acquireWakeLock
07-12 15:28:55.816      337-853/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ acquireWakeLock_l() AudioOut_4 status 0
07-12 15:28:55.826      337-852/? E/msm8974_platform﹕ platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
07-12 15:28:55.856      337-852/? E/audio_hw_primary﹕ [MAXIM] setDSM_tx_Control()....dsm_enable : 1, dsm_opened : 0, adev->snd_card : 0, device_id : 1, adev->mode : 0
07-12 15:28:55.946     955-1004/? E/LocSvc_utils_cfg﹕ W/loc_read_sec_gps_conf: no secgps conf file, using defaults
07-12 15:28:55.966     955-1537/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiV02::startFix(const LocPosMode&):434]: position_mode=0.
07-12 15:28:55.996     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalRespCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientRespIndUnionType, void*) line 125 QMI_LOC_SET_OPERATION_MODE_REQ_V02
07-12 15:28:56.236     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source 10034 txSuccessRate=29.50 rxSuccessRate=22.11 targetRoamBSSID=90:f6:52:77:9b:f0 RSSI=-75
07-12 15:28:56.236     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ [1,436,695,136,247 ms] noteScanStartWorkSource{10034} uid 10034
07-12 15:28:56.256     955-1006/? E/Sensors﹕ Sensor : Meta event
07-12 15:28:56.346    1967-1978/? E/DataBuffer﹕ Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (s{status=Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}, attributions=null})
07-12 15:28:56.356    1967-1978/? E/DataBuffer﹕ Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@342c61ce)
07-12 15:28:56.356    1967-1978/? E/DataBuffer﹕ Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (s{status=Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}, attributions=null})
07-12 15:28:56.366    1967-1978/? E/DataBuffer﹕ Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@300698ef)
07-12 15:28:56.426     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_POSITION_REPORT_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:56.436     955-1703/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 99 QMI_LOC_EVENT_ENGINE_STATE_IND_V02
07-12 15:28:57.806      955-970/? E/PersonaManagerService﹕ inState():  stateMachine is null !!
07-12 15:28:57.846    2399-2655/com.example.akshay.myapplication E/Resources﹕ RunTimeException
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020278
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2345)
            at android.content.res.Resources.startRC(Resources.java:1059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$mRunnable.run(ActivityThread.java:2527)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-12 15:28:58.206    2399-2399/com.example.akshay.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.akshay.myapplication, PID: 2399
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.akshay.myapplication/com.example.akshay.myapplication.showInMaps}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.os.Bundle.getDouble(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2712)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.os.Bundle.getDouble(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.akshay.myapplication.showInMaps.onCreate(showInMaps.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
07-12 15:28:58.396     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ [1,436,695,138,404 ms] noteScanEnd WorkSource{10034}
07-12 15:28:58.396     955-1263/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ wifi setScanResults statecom.android.server.wifi.WifiStateMachine$ConnectedState@3f98adf2 sup_state=COMPLETED debouncing=false
07-12 15:28:58.416      955-955/? E/LocSvc_flp﹕ I/===> int flp_inject_location(FlpLocation*) line 222
07-12 15:28:58.526     955-2678/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
07-12 15:28:59.586    1967-2265/? E/Places﹕ e.a:898: GLS returned HTTP response code 500
07-12 15:29:01.016     955-1005/? E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
07-12 15:29:01.026     955-1296/? E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
07-12 15:29:01.306     955-1006/? E/Sensors﹕ Sensor : Meta event
07-12 15:29:01.376    1967-2265/? E/Places﹕ e.a:898: GLS returned HTTP response code 500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the onCreate method of showInMaps activity, you shouldn't say

```
Intent gotIntent = new Intent();
```

You should instead say

```
Intent gotIntent = getIntent();
```

getIntent() will get the Intent that started this activity, and that's the intent that is holding all your extras. When you say new Intent(), there are no extras at all and hence you get a NullPointerException when you say

```
lat = gotIntent.getExtras().getDouble("Lat");
```

Refer [Android documentation on getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent())

Comment: Thanks Buddy..MyBad I'm a newby in Android Programming